# Delphi: TOAuth2Authenticator with client_credentials

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0

A while ago I wrote a method in Delphi 2010 to get the OAuth2 token using the Indy components (TidHttp). See code below.

I am now doing something new in Delphi 10.4 and would like to use the REST components such as RESTClient, RESTRequest, TOAuth2Authenticator, etc.

Our grant type is Client Credentials but in none of the examples on the net could I find on how to use TOAuth2Authenticator with Client Credentials. Is it even possible?

We have a client id, client secret and token URL. We do not have authorization or redirect endpoints. In Insomnia, the setup will look like this:

[image: Insomnia setup]

Does somebody know how to get the token using TOAuth2Authenticator with grant type = client_credentials?

Here is the Delphi 2010 code:

```
procedure TfrmToken.btnGetTokenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP: TidHttp;
  lsHttpError: string;
  loRequest: TStringStream;
  loRespJson: TMemoryStream;
  liSuper: iSuperObject;
  ldtExpiry: TDateTime;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
  loRespJson := TMemoryStream.Create();
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := False;
    loRequest := TStringStream.Create('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' +
                                       edtKey.Text + '&client_secret='+edtSecret.Text);

    try
      IdHttp.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHttp);
      IdHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      try
        IdHTTP.Post(edtURL.Text, loRequest, loRespJson);
      except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        begin
          lsHttpError := E.ErrorMessage;
        end;
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          lsHttpError := E.Message;
        end;
      end;

      if idHTTP.ResponseCode = 200 then
      begin
        liSuper := SO(StreamToString(loRespJSon));
        edtToken.Text := liSuper.S['access_token'];
        ldtExpiry := IncSecond(Now, liSuper.i['expires_in']);
        edtExpiry.Text := 'Expires in ' + liSuper.S['expires_in'] +
                          ' seconds. Time: ' +
                          FormatDateTime('yyyy/dd/mm hh:nn:ss', ldtExpiry);
      end
      else
      begin
        liSuper := SO(lsHttpError);
        edtToken.Text := IdHTTP.ResponseText;
        edtExpiry.Text := '';
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(loRequest);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(IdHTTP);
    FreeAndNil(loRespJson);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The stock TOAuth2Authenticator doesn't support this out of the box, but you can derive from it and implement your own ChangeAuthCodeToAccesToken. Even the docs at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/REST.Authenticator.OAuth.TOAuth2Authenticator suggest to do that.

Comment: I made an answer to a similar question in another topic. If you had tried to search it should have showed up :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825398/how-to-use-a-rest-api-with-firemonkey/64830594#64830594

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe, like most of the posts I came across, this is very basic and not too helpful.

Comment: @EirikA., unfortunately your post does not deal with my question. I was asking how to use TOAuth2Authenticator. I know how to get it using the other TREST components.

Comment: @Johan, your question suggests that you actually do know what has to be done albeit with Indy. Combined with the current implementation of ChangeAuthCodeToAccesToken it should not be that hard to get a working solution for your problem based on a derived class. Or are you looking for a ready to use implementation?