# How to convert my REST API Delphi project which uses MVCFramework to use standard RAD Studio components instead

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0, ssl-certificate, rest-client, handshake

I develop a project which an old programmer in our company has started. He has used MVCFramework (https://github.com/danieleteti/delphimvcframework) to connect to a portal. Because his code is written so complicated, I gathered it temporarily like this working function just for you to see the logic behind the connection:

```
function ConnectionTest_MinimumCodeJustForStackoverflowUsersToSeeHowItWorks: Boolean;
var
  FBaseURL, FAuthURL, FClientID, FClientSecret, FAccessToken: string;
  FSSLSocket: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  FRestClient: MVCFramework.RESTClient.TRESTClient;
  http: TIdHTTP;
  ParameterList: TStringList;
  ping: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  FBaseURL := 'https://www.the_portal_addresse.de';
  FAuthURL := 'https://auth.the_portal_addresse.de/auth/token';
  FClientID := 'Bla'; 
  FClientSecret := 'Bla'; 
  FSSLSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  FSSLSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
  FRestClient := MVCFramework.RESTClient.TRESTClient.Create(FBaseURL, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, FSSLSocket);
  FRestClient.ContentType('application/json');
  FRestClient.Accept('application/json');
  FAccessToken := '';
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  ParameterList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    try
      http.HandleRedirects := False;
      http.IOHandler := FSSLSocket;
      http.Request.ContentType := CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED;
      http.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
      ParameterList.add('grant_type=client_credentials');
      ParameterList.add('client_id=' + FClientID);
      ParameterList.add('client_secret=' + FClientSecret);
      FAccessToken := http.Post(FAuthURL, ParameterList);
      FAccessToken := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(FAccessToken).GetValue<string>('access_token');
    except
      Exit;
    end;
    FRestClient.SetBearerToken(FAccessToken);
    ping := FRestClient.doGet(BasePath + '/system/ping', []).BodyAsString;
    if LowerCase(ping) <> 'pong' then
      Exit;
    Result := True;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(ParameterList);
    FreeAndNil(http);
    FreeAndNil(TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL);
    FreeAndNil(FRestClient);
  end;
end;
```

Note that I'm not going to use this code in my project but I want to change it. Also I have no access to this programmer because he is fired!

This function is working with MVCFramework but I cannot use the `TRESTClient` component which is defined in `REST.Client` instead, because `REST.Client.TRESTClient.Create` differs from the `MVCFramework.RESTClient.TRESTClient.Create`.

Maybe it is a good idea that I use the MVCFramework as well but I want to learn why my converted code (without MVCFramework) does not work and I get this error:

```
Error connecting with SSL.
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure.
```

What I have tried is:

```
function ConnectionTest_MinimumCodeJustForStackoverflowUsersToSeeHowItWorks_2: Boolean;
var
  ...
  FRestClient: REST.Client.TRESTClient;
  ...
begin
  ...
  FBaseURL := 'https://www.the_portal_addresse.de:443';
  FAuthURL := 'https://auth.the_portal_addresse.de:443/auth/token';
  ...
  FRestClient := REST.Client.TRESTClient.Create(FBaseURL);
  ...
      FAccessToken := http.Post(FAuthURL, ParameterList); // ERROR!
  ...
```

I also tried placing the `TRest...` components on a form, and also `OAuth1Authenticator` and `OAuth2Authenticator` components, but I couldn't go further because I didn't know how should I set the `'grant_type=client_credentials'`.

How can I convert my function to work using `REST.Client.TRESTClient` instead of `MVCFramework.RESTClient.TRestClient`?

Comment: I answered a similar question about how to get a token when you use grant_type=client_credentials. Have a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825398/how-to-use-a-rest-api-with-firemonkey
Regarding the SSL error, that might be old SSL libraries or old and unsupported Windows version.

Comment: I have tried that before like the code you wrote in that answer, but I did not succeed because i must use the sslvSSLv23 and I don't know how and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG! I've discovered the problem! It turns out the issue was not with the code, but rather with incorrect system settings set by our IT administrator. We are using a virtual machine with Delphi installed, along with numerous components, certificates, Windows settings, and software installations. In our large main project, which takes a significant amount of time to compile and run, I initially wrote the first function, but modified function in a new project located in a temporary folder. The intention was to speed up testing by running the project separately.

After numerous attempts and exhaustive research (which gave me a headache), I finally identified the cause. It appears that certain DLL files, specifically "**libeay32.dll**" and "**ssleay32.dll**" must reside in the same directory as my executable file. These DLL files were present in the folders of our main project, which is why the original function worked while my changes did not. Ideally, our IT administrator should have correctly configured the environment path settings for Delphi or Windows, which would have prevented me from encountering this problem.

I believe it's important for everyone to be aware of this issue, which is why I posted this answer. I want to express my sincere gratitude to all the participants, particularly [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2236885/david-schwartz), who dedicated a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused by the component names and missing the bigger picture: MVC is a specific kind of approach to managing resources. It bridges three different things: Model, View, and Controller. If you want to switch to a different paradigm, then you're going to need to rewrite your Client entirely.

I like to start with an example that has the different parts that I want, and then change the individual endpoints and then their implementation.

Remember that part of this is running on a server and part is a client accessing that (remote) service. Don't get confused by the fact that they may both be on the same machine or it's going to break as soon as you separate them.

I'd love to point you to an example, but they don't like posting links here, and an example is way too long to post in a reply as there would be several different units involved.

First, cut ties with the MVC library. Don't try using what's there. Start over. There's only ONE TRESTClient component, and it's designed to talk to a Server. You seem to only be focusing on the Client side here, so I'm not sure what the Server is needing, but accessing the server from a client can be very simple depending on what the service requires.

If you show an example of the service you're trying to connect to (the specs) then we could suggest code to access it. But trying to do a "conversion" from MVC to something else is way more complicated than just coding something from scratch.

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your answer. If you look at my working code, you can see that the server requires these things: SSL, OAUTH2, grant_type=client_credentials and so on. There are other things that are after authorization process like Bearer but I have problem with the very first step, authorization and handshake. I hate what I have done, copy and paste the code from other programmers! I want to learn and master exactly what I'm coding. I want to know what is going on there. If my boss had told me to write the program from the beginning, I couldn't have done it.

Comment: I understand, but you have to start somewhere, and starting with a working example has always been my preferred approach. It's a lot quicker than having to learn everything first. You can learn a lot by going through the code with the debugger and seeing what's going on, especially for stuff like this where there's a lot of asynchronous activity that's not obvious just reading specs and the code. When you're working with services, there isn't a "straight line" through the code, and especially with a framework like MVC. Start with something that's working and trace through the code to learn it.

Comment: I keep typing stuff and realize what I said before: the Client part is only 1/2 of the equation. The SERVICE side is the other half. What you're doing is like showing code used to call a DLL without describing any of the DLL's interfaces. It's impossible to know what OPTIONS you have based on what you've disclosed. The goal is to talk with the back-end and display the results somehow. All you've shown is the front-end that you DON'T WANT. What you need to know is what the back-end requires. Reverse-engineering the front-end is bass-ackward. START with the back-end's API spec.

Comment: The documentation on how to connect to the server is written in German in some PDFs that are not published on the web and i have received them directly via email from the company that provided the API for companies like us, so unfortunately I can't put a link here.

Comment: Well, you don't need to post them here. Most APIs tend to have something simple like GetVersion that lets you set up your interface and test it out. Also, see if they have a swagger page on their site; it'll give you the details you need, and it might be in English.

Answer (score 0):

SSL problem to solve first:

> FSSLSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

This option is not enabled by default on the current client libraries any more.
If the server still needs this weak cipher, then check how to enable it in the new client.

Comment: I changed it to sslvTLSv1_2 and it works with the first code but still does not work with my modification. The means the server supports old and new ssl and tls versions.